How long will RE be in Beta?
Might be a standard question, but I could not find the answer on Area 51: how long will this site be in Beta? I have just seen another site (Startups) being offline with even better statistics. How much time do we have to make this site an accepted one?

It would be a terrible shame if reverseengineering.stackexchange.com was closed. However, it looks like Startups wasn't closed because of poor statistics:
From https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12630 -

The site was closed not because it lacked activity in general, but
  because the community that once started it had for the most part left,
  and wasn't being replaced with new people as folks found the site.
...
There were plenty of high rep users, but many had not been seen in well over a year.

I don't think we have that problem, so even though our stats aren't quite as good as Startups', perhaps we have a better chance of surviving the Beta :)

Thanks for the additional information. Looking at the statistics, it seems like it was closed because only one of the points was not fulfilled.

measuring a section's "maturabity" in relation of activity makes RE  a "gown-up" section a long ago, but the importance does also counts, this sction is far worthy to be graded than other sections which just transited from "a nonesens in high activity rate" to "nonesens in slow motion"
